# How do you punctuate the end of a quote within a quote: "Billy said, 'This is acceptable.' "

Tags: word-usage

At the end of such a sentence, does the single quote come before the punctuation?

If it does not, is a space between the single quotation and double quotation marks necessary?

`>>`, `' "`   or `'"`?

I ask because the publisher's font does not show a space like it seems to here, which looks confusing, so I'm wondering if this is acceptable, or do we just live with the oddity of what appears to be a triple quotation mark)

Comment: Putting a space in authorizes the word processor to start a new line just before the " which is not desired at all!  So use a non-breaking space or (as lefthander said) a thinspace.

Answer (score 1):

If the publisher's font has a hair space or a thin space (As would be marked *hr#* or *thin#* in the old days when writers used typewriters and then added notes about things their typewriter couldn't do), or perhaps even a six-per-em or four-per-em space, then I would use that.

Otherwise I'd just judge by the font; whether ’” or ’ ” looked closer to the ideal of ’ ” in the given font.

Answer (score 0):

In American usage, a period at the end of a sentence with a nested quote should go inside the innermost quotation marks (see http://leo.stcloudstate.edu/research/puncquotes.html#Comma/Period and http://www.lawprose.org/blog/?p=2709). The [Chicago Manual of Style](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Punctuation/faq0011.html) suggests that it's common typographic practice to insert a thin space between a single quote and a double quote, and that the space should be inserted by the typesetter (if it is not automatically inserted by typesetting software).